# Identify this classical piece (possibly called Impromptu)

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

(repost from [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/52748/help-me-identify-this-classical-piece-possibly-entitled-impromptu) as this is the more appropriate place) 
[image]

Comment: The title says "Ekspromt", and it translates "Impromtu" as you said...

Comment: Yea but I have no idea as to who the composer is or so. I only managed to get the first page of this piece.

Comment: What is the text on top RHS of page - looks like "Com...something" ? may give further clue.

Comment: @mercurial, for future questions, here you can learn [how you can improve your question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/368/1721) 
and increase your chances for find the music you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an Impromptu by [Anton Arensky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton_Arensky), Op. 25, No. 1. The score can be found [here](http://ks.petruccimusiclibrary.org/files/imglnks/usimg/9/90/IMSLP02722-Arensky_op25.pdf), and a video can be found [here](https://youtu.be/sSfwSFhb_gE?t=8s).